# Editor in CollectionView Focus

Tags: android, editor, maui, collectionview

I am trying to do my first .NET Maui app. I have a Listview in a StackLayout. Inside the Listview, I have a CollectionView. All of my data binding is pulling information as expected. The issue I'm having is with an Entry/Editor item in my collection view. The data binding is working fine on these two controls. What's not working is clicking on the Entry or Editor to change the data; the keyboard doesn't pop-up. I've confirmed that the "Focused" event does not fire for the newly added CollectionView item. If I add a second CollectionView item, I can then select the previously added    CollectionView item and the keyboard pops-up and the Focused Event fires. At that point, I can then select the newly added CollectionView item too.  What am I doing wrong in order in order to use the Entry/Editor control on the newly added item?

```
<ListView   x:Name="OrderListVeiw"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                HasUnevenRows="true">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Grid ColumnSpacing="8"
                          BackgroundColor="Black">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding OrderId}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Status" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding OrderStatus}" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Customer" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CustId}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="Consignee" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ShipTo}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="City, State" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding CityState}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="PO" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding PO}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="Cust Ref." />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding CustRef}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="PU#" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding PU}" TextColor="White" />
                            <CollectionView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}" 
                                            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                            SelectionMode="Single"
                                            
                                            ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                                            HeightRequest="320" >
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Entry Text="{Binding LoadNo}" ReturnType="Done" Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="White" />
                                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageBytes, Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageSource}}"
                                                   HeightRequest="150" />
                                            
                                            <Editor Placeholder="Photo Description" Text="{Binding Description}" Keyboard="Text" BackgroundColor="White" 
                                                    AutoSize="TextChanges" MaximumWidthRequest="150" Focused="Editor_Focused" x:Name="EditDesc"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0" 
                                    Text="Photo"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:OrdersViewModel}},Path=TakePhotoCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding OrderId}"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                                    Text="Labels" 
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:OrdersViewModel}},Path=PrintLabelsCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding OrderId}"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="2" 
                                    Text="Details" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding OrderId}"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:OrdersViewModel}},Path=GetOrderDetailsCommand}"
                                    
                                    />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: nesting a CollectionView in a ListView is generally not a good idea.  That might not be the root of your problems but worth considering

Comment: What's a better approach to take then? I want to be able to add 0-10 pictures to each ListView item.

Comment: Use one page with the outer list and a second page with the inner list.  Selecting a row on the first page leads to the 2nd with details for that row

Comment: thanks. Will give that route a go.

Comment: @DavidGerst Have you solved the question?

Comment: I opted to use one page for outer list and second page for inner list as I couldn't get it to work on single page.  That did resolve the issue.